# How to get the MySQL query results into a ArrayList<object>

Tags: java, mysql, sql, arraylist, resultset

I have SQL query which results in multiple columns. I want to execute this query and get the results into my `ArrayList<>` instead of the `ResultSet`.
My class for the column definitions is

```
public class Record{
    private String FileName;
    private String FileID;
    private String Loan;
    private String Page;
}
```

Query is :

```
String query = "SELECT FileName, FileID, loanNumnber, PageNumber FROM table";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

I want the results of the query in **recordData** object.

```
ArrayList<Record> recordData = new ArrayList<Record>;
```

Please suggest how the arraylist can be populated directly with correct mapping.

Comment: Use a OR mapper like Hibernate, JDO etc. or do it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following code snippet if you want to implement by yourself. It will convert the result set to `Record` objects and add it to the `ArrayList`.

```
Record record;
while(rs.next()){

     record = new record();

     String fileName  = rs.getString("FileName");
     String fileID = rs.getString("FileID");
     String loanNumnber = rs.getString("loanNumnber");
     String pageNumber = rs.getString("PageNumber");

    record.setFileName(fileName);
    record.setFileID(fileID);
    record.setLoan(loanNumnber);
    record.setPage(pageNumber);

    recordData.add(record)
}

rs.close();
```

Otherwise, if you want to use any third party frameworks then there are lot of options such as Hibernate, iBatis etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mybatis.
Please use the ORM.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping

Answer (score 0):

You should use OR mapper like Hibernate. Thanks POJO classes you can do whan you want.
Some readings:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_examples.htm

http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/hibernate-tutorials/

Answer (score 0):

Add parenthesis "()" to this line in your code so that it looks like this:

**`ArrayList<Record> recordData = new ArrayList<Record>();`**